# Object Refrence not Set while New Keyword is being used

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this CMember Class. I Write something like

```
Dim moMember As CMember
moMember = New CMember
```

Then I want to set a variable to its CentreId property:

```
moMember.CentreId = CentreNumber
```

Both are Integers, however a Object Refrence Not Set exception is thrown, WHY?

Comment: It must be part of the code you haven't given us.  The debugger should also give more information.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `moMember` is not `null`, but that the property setter (`CentreId`) uses some internal state that is my correctly configured, and is throwing the exception as a consequence. An event being invoked without a null-check would be a classic example, as would some inner object that holds the state. Check the setter to see what is happening. If the value you are assigning (`CentreNumber`) is a property, it could also be thrown from in there; again: check the getter.

It ***is*** possible for `new` on a class to return `null`, but only in an ***extreme*** edge case that can not happen by accident. Thus I *very much* doubt that `moMember` is `null` - the debugger will tell you quicky enough.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other code between initialization and setting the `CentreId` there should not be any way `moMember`is null. Maybe the exception occurs during construction of `CMember`.